# How to deploy static resources to tomcat without WEB-INF?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I want to create a `war` package that only contains static resources. Eg:

`/src/main/resources/files/example.xml`

Therefore, I created the following `maven` config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
    <groupId>my.domain</groupId>
    <artifactId>testpackage</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

When deploying on `tomcat8`, I get the following structure:

`localhost:8080/testpackage/WEB-INF/classes/files/example.xml`

What I want is being able to access the static file directly using:

`localhost:8080/testpackage/files/example.xml`

Question: how could I create a deployable war that explodes in a path without `/WEB-INF/classes`?

(I know I could just copy the files into `/webapps` folder manually. But others should be able to deploy the static content just through the tomcat manager web interface, thus is need a proper war).

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html: web resources are under src/main/webapp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web resources are under `src/main/webapp`.

`src/main/resources` is for classpath resources.

See the [project layout documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).